# Parsing ISO 8601 duration format to Joda duration - IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, jodatime, iso8601

I am trying to parse ISO 8601 duration of 1 month to Joda Duration object.
Can you please help me why this line of code

```
 Duration duration = Duration.parse("P1M");
```

throws

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "P1M"
at org.joda.time.convert.StringConverter.getDurationMillis(StringConverter.java:111)
at org.joda.time.base.BaseDuration.<init>(BaseDuration.java:105)
at org.joda.time.Duration.<init>(Duration.java:209)
at org.joda.time.Duration.parse(Duration.java:59)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, it should be a `Period` not a `Duration` as it is one month long so try this instead:

```
Period period = Period.parse("P1M");
```

Indeed a `Duration` needs to be expressed in **an exact amount of milliseconds** and as a month cannot be exactly expressed in milliseconds as it changes from one month to another it cannot be a `Duration`.

More details about `Period` and `Duration` [here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html#Durations)

Answer (score 1):

The `Duration` is used to represent time-based amount of time, like seconds and nanoseconds.

To represent data-based amount of time, you should consider use `Period`.